# JavaScript: What is an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have these few lines of code:

```
 (function(exports){
 // Do something
 })(typeof exports===typeof {}&&exports===this?exports:this.webdriver=this.webdriver||{})
```

What does this mean? How can I use this function?

Comment: +4? `oO` Personally I don't see any context here...

Comment: It's all about SEO. Upvoted.

Comment: You can't. It's anonymous, hence it has no name. It's called when it's created, and if no reference is passed, it's lost right after.

Comment: the function without name is called anonymous function. like you have mentioned in your code.